# How to get ssl .key file from ssls.com .crt, .p7b and .ca-bundle?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I've re-downloaded my ssl credentials and put them on my server ssl folder. **I've checked the other questions regarding this but none were explicit and gave clear commands on how to perform this exactly.** Should I generate .key with openssl? And how? Tyvm for your help...

Comment: Have you sold your issue? Same question in here